# iOS file size during write using only C/C++ APIs

Tags: c++, ios, file

**Purpose:** I am monitoring file writes in a particular directory on iOS using BSD kernel queues, and poll for file sizes to determine write ends (when the size stops changing). The basic idea is to refresh a folder only *after* any number of file copies coming from iTunes sync. I have a completely working Objective-C implementation for this but I have my reasons for needing to implement the same thing in C++ only.

**Problem:** The one thing stopping me is that I can't find a C or C++ API that will get the correct file size during a write. Presumably, one must exist because Objective-C's [NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:] seems to work and we all know it is just calling a C API underneath.

**Failed Solutions:**

1. I have tried using stat() and lstat() to get st_size and even st_blocks for allocated block count, and they return correct sizes for most files in a directory, but when there is a file write happening that file's size never changes between poll intervals, and every subsequent file iterated in that directory have a bad size.
2. I have tried using fseek and ftell but they are also resulting in a very similar issue.
3. I have also tried modified date instead of size using stat() and st_mtimespec, and the date doesn't appear to change during a write - not that I expected it to.

Going back to NSFileManager's ability to give me the right values, does anyone have an idea what C API call that [NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:] is actually using underneath?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
It appears that this has less to do with in-progress write operations and more with specific files. After closer inspection there are some files which always return a size, and other files that never return a size when using the C API (but will work fine with the Objective-C API). Even creating a copy of the "good" files the C API does not want to give a size for the copy but works fine with the original "good" file. I have both failures and successes with text (xml) files and binary (zip) files. I am using iTunes to add these files to the iPad's app's Documents directory. It is an iPad Mini Retina.

**Update 2 - Answer:**
Probably any of the above file size methods will work, if your path isn't invisibly trashed, like mine was. See accepted answer on why the path was trashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this weird behavior turned out to be a problem with the paths, which result in strings that will print normally, but are likely trashed in memory enough that file descriptors sometimes didn't like it (thus only occurring in certain file paths). I was using the dirent API to iterate over the files in a directory and concatenating the dir path and file name erroneously.

**Bad Path Concatenation:** Obviously (or apparently not-so-obvious at runtime) str-copying over three times is not going to end well.

```
char* fullPath = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(file) + 2);
strcpy(fullPath, dir);
strcpy(fullPath, "/");
strcpy(fullPath, file);
long sizeBytes = getSize(fullPath);
free(fullPath);
```

**Correct Path Concatenation:** Use proper str-concatenation.

```
char* fullPath = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir) + strlen(file) + 2);
strcpy(fullPath, dir);
strcat(fullPath, "/");
strcat(fullPath, file);
long sizeBytes = getSize(fullPath);
free(fullPath);
```

Long story short, it was sloppy work on my part, via two typos.